# Persitent shopping cart not showing 'remember me'. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, persistent

I've enable the peristent shopping cart in

> Shop > Config > Client > Persistent Shopping Cart

and enable the "Remember Me" part, but the checkbox is not showing on frontend, why ? I have a Magento_Sales folder in my app/design, maybe it's because of this ?

PS : Magento 2.2.5 and all caches cleared

Edit :

Here's what I have with path hint

[image]

I've remove my customer_account_login.xml file from my folder and the checkbox is appearing, but the login and password are not stored on front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is persistence shopping cart?**

In **Magento 2** store, a persistent cart is one of the relatively effective features to decrease the abandonment cart. The persistent cart allows storing the product in the shopping cart the customers have not completed yet even when they sign out your site.

**How to enable persistent cart in Magento 2**

1. On the Admin sidebar, click Stores.
2. In the Settings section, choose Configuration.
3. In the Customers section on the left panel, choose Persistent Shopping Cart.
4. To enable the persistent shopping cart and display additional options, set Enable Persistence to Yes.
   [image]
5. In the Persistence Lifetime (seconds) field, enter the length of time, in seconds, that you want the persistent cookie to last.
6. Set Enable “Remember Me” to Yes:
7. To preselect the Remember Me checkbox, set Remember Me Default Value to Yes.
8. Set Clear Persistence on Log Out
9. Set Persist Shopping Cart

**Where persistent cart Remember Me display**

It will display on login page under the password field.

**Troubleshoot**

1. As per your question, there is no relation with override template **Magento_Sales** in your theme, so ignore it.
2. Enable template path hint & check the template
3. Review the `magento\module-persistent` core module view & block file.
4. See in your **add/design** folder have you overrided `magento\module-persistent` module file or **login.phtml** file?
5. You can search in your directory **app/code** & **app/design** `name="persistent_remember_me"` is exist?

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. For the 4, no I didn't. For the 5, i have this. The only block I have with this name is a block that I have added manually added to show the checkbox (added after trying to enable the remember me from the admin)

Comment: Ok, now change theme (set Luma default theme) from `admin > content > design > configuration` and see checkbox is display?

Comment: And also search this block `persistent.remember.me` is somewhere removed in XML?

Comment: Nop, not removed at all. But I removed my customer_account_login.xml from the file and the checkbox is appearing, but my login/password are not stored

Comment: If you set `Clear Persistence on Sign Out` to `Yes` then login/password are clear when you log out.

Comment: Persistence is used for "Someone want to keep the products in the shopping cart after the customer logout." i don't think so it will save the login/password information.

Comment: What should I do to do that so ?

Comment: Ok, the problem was the settings of the phone (doesn't store passwords by defaut). I'm giving you the reward, thanks for the details.

Comment: Thanks for the Appreciation :) Also +1 for a nice question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enable `Remember Me` then checkbox should show in login page ,check in store view whether it is disable from there.

`Magento_Sales` doesn't affect to that checkbox. it came from files

```
vendor\magento\module-persistent\view\frontend\templates\remember_me.phtml

vendor\magento\module-persistent\view\frontend\web\template\remember-me.html
```

Enable Template Path Hints and Check these files are extended/removed in your theme and modified or not.

**Edit :**
check in theme any of `customer_account_create.xml` file you have removed block name `form.additional.info` or `persistent.remember.me`
?
 add `customer_account_create.xml` file and set remove false and add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Persistent\Block\Form\Remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="Magento_Persistent::remember_me.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: See my updated answer. Btw, I'm not overriding those files in my theme

Comment: i have updated too